# Set flag in nix package

Tags: nix

I'm trying to link my project with static openssl. I've noticed that there is flag `static` in openssl package: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/d6a12e8d9e0a4ac35ed401881e0d3160c764ac36/pkgs/development/libraries/openssl/default.nix#L5 but i have no idea how it can be set when using it. (`pkgs.openssl ...`?).

*Currently I "solved" it by using `pkgs.pkgsStatic.openssl`, but it have very annoying side effect on form of `gcc` and other not related dependencies being recompiled statically (what the hell?).*

How can use `openssl` package with static flag enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the arguments passed to a package with `override`. This is enough if you just want to build a static `openssl`:

```
pkgs.openssl.override {
    static = true;
}
```

To build other packages using this customised `openssl`, it must be added back into `nixpkgs` using an overlay:

```
self: super: {
    openssl = super.openssl.override {
        static = true;
    };
}
```

This overlay can be placed in `~/.config/nixpkgs/overlays/openssl-static.nix` or added to `configuration.nix`'s `nixpkgs.overlays`.